# Wired ethernet connection failed on 20.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

Using 20.04 on a wired ethernet.  Was working fine, then suddenly stopped.
Using terminal ;

```
 lshw -C network
```

Returns:

```
*-network disabled
.........Then all the correct data of the appropriate card and then...... 
    logical name:  enp7s0
```

Also used

ip addr

Returns:

```
3: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/ether  etc etc
```

So both confirm ethernet is disconnected.

Can access YAML file ie  `01-network-manager-all.YAML`   but this does not show any of the detail, so presumably needs changing - but how?

Or is there another approach?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.